# on create on pause functionality

Tags: android, android-activity

Since i am new to android,what i am doing is setting few textview in my second activity and showing the result to my first activity by clicking a button but when i move back to my second activity the data on textview vanishes which in turn vanishes the data on textview of first activity.can any one help me by explaining where should i set data and from where i should get data.

first activity

```
public void ifHangerButtonAction(View view)
    { 
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FastingHanger.class);
       intent.setClass(this, FastingHanger.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID_SECOND",globalVariable.fastingHourValue );
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID_Third",globalVariable.feedingTime );
       startActivity(intent);
       System.out.println("going to second activity");
       finish();
    }
```

second activity

```
globalVariable.setFastingHourValue(fastingHourValue);
    System.out.println("globalVariable.setFastingHourValue(fastingHourValue)="+fastingHourValue);
    globalVariable.setName(getName);
    System.out.println("globalVariable.setName(getName)="+getName);
    //rs
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID",fastingHourValue );
    intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID_NEW",getName );
    startActivity(intent);
    System.out.println("going to first activity");
    finish();
```

Comment: It will obviously vanish the data as you leave the activity and switch to another activity. If you want to keep the data as it is then you are supposed to store it into sharedpreference and need to access it and set it everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Use Intent bundle to pass data between activities. In your case if you want to pass information from the second activity to the first then you do the following:

Second Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID",fastingHourValue );
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID_NEW",getName );
startActivity(intent);
```

First Activity:

In your onCreate method:

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        int x = extras.getInt(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID);
        int y = extras.getInt(MainActivity.EXTRA_ID_NEW);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
     }
```

More information about intents can be found here: [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)